# Assistance required in writing list of data to a particular column in an excel file using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have written a code which reads data in formula cells of an excel and returns a string and now i want to write the list of string values to a particular sheet and a particular column. Could anybody provide me an sample code snippet.
Ex: Write the list of data to column "C" of an excel file.
My code looks like:

```
 @Test 

    public void SampleCustNumFormat() throws Exception { 
    String [][] myXL = getExcelData();

    //See what has been read from Excel
    for (int i=0; i<xRows; i++)
    {
      for (int j=3; j<xCols; j++)
      {
          System.out.println (" Cust Num " + myXL[i][j]);
      }
    }
}

public  String [][] getExcelData() throws Exception {
String [][] tabArray=null;
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\SCE docs\\Automation\\CustomerAccount_Information.xls"); 
    HSSFWorkbook myWB = new HSSFWorkbook(fi); 
    HSSFSheet mySheet = myWB.getSheetAt(0); 

    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = myWB.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    xRows = mySheet.getLastRowNum()+1; 
    xCols = mySheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum(); 
    tabArray = new String [xRows][xCols]; 

    for (int i=0;i<xRows;i++) 
    { 
      HSSFRow row = mySheet.getRow(i); 
      for (int j=3;j<xCols;j++) 
      { 
        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j); 
        CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
        String value = evaluateFormula(cellValue);
        tabArray[i][j]=value;
      }
    }
  return tabArray;
   }

private String evaluateFormula(CellValue cellValue) throws Exception{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

int type = cellValue.getCellType();
Object result=null;
switch (type) {

    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
      result = cellValue.getBooleanValue();
      break;
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
      result = cellValue.getNumberValue();
      break;
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
      result = cellValue.getStringValue();
      break;
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
      break;
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
      break;

    // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never happen
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
     break;
   }

  return result.toString();
   }
 }





My Output list of string values is : 
 Cust Num CustAccNum
 Cust Num 2-23-456-7891
 Cust Num 2-00-006-7891
 Cust Num 2-03-456-7891
 Cust Num 2-00-234-5678
 Cust Num 2-00-023-4891
 Cust Num 2-00-234-7891
 Cust Num 2-00-345-6781
```

Comment: Did you check out the [quick guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am clearly understanding your problem, then you just want to write some data in the particular column of each row. If it is correct then following will helo you.

```
  //sheet is the excel sheet and data[] is the array of data you need to write.
  For (int i=0; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)
      sheet.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue(data[i]);
```

For details use quick [guide link](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) as suggested by n0741337.

Comment: how do i accept. i am pretty new to this site., Also could u please help me in resolving this error :When i use the below line of code, the system throws an error :Type mismatch : Cannot convert void to HSSFCell . the code is    HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue(myXL[k]);

Comment: ok, This is my actual code and i want to read the data from an excel file which has formulas and write the list of array to a particular column of another excel. Could you please review the below code and help me in resolving the issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Test 
 public void SampleCustNumFormat() throws Exception { String [] myXL = getExcelData(); for (int i=0; i<xRows; i++)
        {
    System.out.println (" Cust Num " + myXL[i]);    }
        
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream ("C:\\SCE docs\\Automation\\TestExcelData.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook myWB = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
        HSSFSheet sheet = myWB.getSheetAt(0);                  
        for (int k=1; k<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); k++)
        {
        HSSFCell cell = Sheet.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue(myXL[k]);
        } myWB.write(out);out.close();
}

Comment: @user1564024 If you have a different problem than the raised one, raise it as new question, but do not post it as comment. Or if it is related to the same question, edit and update your question.

Comment: BTW you have initialized `sheet` but using `Sheet` update it as following.

`HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue(myXL[k]);`

Comment: I have posted a new question, could u please look into the code in detail